# How to run any cronjobs using Objective-C at iOS Platform

Tags: ios, scheduling, cron

Is there any way to run schedulers / schedule programs for example Cron Jobs using  Objective-C at iOS Platform?

I need to create a schedule update to my ios, lets say for example every five days my app will fetch something to the internet and update the database I also want user to set the interval.

I think for this purpose cron jobs can be a vital part. Is there any suggestions or other ways?

Comment: In addition to wyatt's answer, check http://www.macworld.com/article/1164616/how_ios_multitasking_really_works.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no access to cron in iOS. In fact, iOS generally cuts down the ability to have your app stay running in the background -- user battery life is more important than developer convenience.

A poor man's approach would be to use CoreData to record a timestamp of last update, then check when the app is opened, and periodically while the app is running, if there should be a data update. If there are updates that come out while the user is not using the app you might want to look at push notifications and running something server-side.